# How to tell "1.0" is a float but an integer in C language?

Tags: c, floating-point

I have a program that accept orders by reading commands from a file.
In this file some commands are "float string", like "1.0","2.0", but they are invalid, what the program need is integer, like "1","2". So, how can I make the program understand the commands like "1.0" is invalid? Is there any neat way to do this?

```
    char buf[CMDSIZE];
    if(fgets(buf, CMDSIZE, stdin))      //buf likes this: "1.0 \n"
    {
        *prio = 1; *command = -1; *ratio =1.0;
        // I need to make sure that command is not "1.0" or something like this              
        sscanf(buf, "%d", command);
        switch(*command){....blahblah......}
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show us the code that's reading those numbers.

Comment: try sscanf(buf, "%f", command) for float value

Comment: @RolandXu It is my software debugging homework. I just find here is the bug, because the correct program will not accept "1.0". If I change `%d` to `%f`, the bug is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to use `strtol`.

This will parse a base-10 integer.  The pointer `e` will point to the first character after the integer.  You can check to make sure it's a NUL byte and signal an error otherwise.  (You also have to check that the input isn't empty.)

If you want to allow spaces / newlines after the number, you can do that too.  Note that `strtol` eats leading whitespace -- but not trailing whitespace.

```
long v;
char *e;
v = strtol(buf, &e, 10);
if (!buf[0] || *e) {
    error();
}
// v has number
```

**Footnote:** Checking for overflow and underflow with `strtol` is a little weird.  You have to set `errno` to 0 first, call `strtol`, then check if the result is `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX` and if `errno` is set to `ERANGE`.

Comment: Awesome! it works. But I am wondering why C makes this so complex?

Comment: @stevenYANG: C has a fairly minimal standard library.  If the calling conventions for `strtol` are not to your liking, just write a wrapper function.

Answer (score 3):

Both `scanf("%d"....)` and `scanf("%f"....)` will succeed and return 1 when reading the input **1.0**. (sscanf works the same way.) It's just that with `"%d"`, it will stop reading before the decimal point.

You can use the format specifier `%n` with sscanf to see how many characters were read, and then look if the buffer contains more stuff afterwards.

Or, which might be easier, just look at the contents in the buffer with your own code, instead of sscanf, to see if there are only digits there.

Comment: Actually, I do as your second offer. The real wrong buffer looks like "1.0 2 0.3\n", and I split it into a array.["1.0","2","0.3"]. But I still don't know what to do next to distinguish "1.0" is invalid.I will try your first suggestion.

Comment: Another thing you can do is to try both scanf("%d%n"....) and scanf("%f%n"....). If the floating-point number has more characters, you've found an error.

Comment: Your solution is good, but I think Dietrich's is much handy.Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

in your special case, just to check difference between 1 and 1.0
use the code:

```
int ret = scanf("%d.%d",&i,&j);
```

if inputs is 1, the scanf only assign one value, the ret is 1
if inputs is 1.0, the scanf assign two value, the ret is 2.
if inputs is abcd, the scanf can't assign any value, the ret is 0

and regarding the return value of scanf, fscanf etc.

In C99 standard 7.19.6.4 The scanf function

The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before
any conversion. Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items
assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early
matching failure

Comment: As far as I understand, the "input failure" means failure to get bytes from the stream, not any failure to convert, so if no conversions can be done, for example trying to convert "bob" to an integer, 0 will be returned. I'm not sure if this is what you mean?

Comment: @Thomas Padron-McCarthy: Yes.I think so. if can't convert, it return zero, not the EOF. So you are correct. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use scanf with %f to store it as a floating point value
example or scan with %d to store it as an integer but it will not count the decimal

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
float i;
int a;
printf("Enter a number which is a floating point value");
scanf("%f,%d",&i,&a);
}
```

here using scanf and %f we are storing it in a float variable i so 1.5,1.0
or any number with a decimal will be stored or if we only use the %d it will only store 1,2,3,4 any number without the decimal i.e if we give 2.5 it will only take 2